# Access cookies through an API on AMP page

Tags: api, cookies, amp-html

I am converting a page to google AMP and need to access cookies to set a view of a division. I am thinking of creating an API for this.

The API will just return all the cookies available on my domain in JSON format. I will hit the API using `<amp-state>` component and store the returned JSON. Then will take actions according to this state.

Is this a valid approach to use in AMP? Is there any security flow in this?

Comment: This is a valid approach (although it feels wrong to make a network request for accessing information locally available). Can you provide more details about your use case, maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: We are a lead generation website. we store user information in a cookie. So if the cookie is available at client, we just show a lead button instead of lead submission form (which asks for user details). So I need to access the cookie to decide whether to show the button or form. Please tell me if there is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Using amp-list is the right approach in this case. amp-list makes a request to your server, which can read the cookie and return an appropriate JSON response. You can render then the form / button inside the amp-list using amp-mustache.

This samples demonstrates how to do this: https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/favorite_button/.